# Cardano-graphql doesn't return sync percentage

Tags: cardano-db-sync, cardano-graphql

when I first started It was returning the sync percentage, and the logs of `cardano-graphql` was like this:

```
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":30,"module":"Server","msg":"Sync Progress: cardano-db-sync: 74.94% | Asset: 196%","time":"2022-08-11T06:50:21.657Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":30,"module":"HasuraClient","assetId":"14a3455f71c435a04ea1fdb50a3ef4c1cab0e79fb1565627ac66a57552415645","msg":"Adding metadata to asset","time":"2022-08-11T06:50:24.142Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":30,"module":"HasuraClient","assetId":"ac485b0065d814e7a984a64e14afc924859033b3171b78a5939cb90559474e46545331","msg":"Adding metadata to asset","time":"2022-08-11T06:50:24.185Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":30,"module":"HasuraClient","assetId":"a32ea58b0d2d0afedddb31dd2e9596c5e3de3451eea207a929574aa4426f62636f696e","msg":"Adding metadata to asset","time":"2022-08-11T06:50:24.235Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":30,"module":"Server","msg":"Sync Progress: cardano-db-sync: 74.94% | Asset: 196%","time":"2022-08-11T06:50:34.399Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":30,"module":"Server","msg":"Sync Progress: cardano-db-sync: 74.94% | Asset: 196%","time":"2022-08-11T06:50:46.357Z","v":0}
```

However, I had to restart the docker components so I did run `docker-compose stop` command to stop all and started again right now it doesn't give response instead returns:

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

and this is the logs of `cardano-graphql`:

```
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":30,"module":"Server","msg":"GraphQL HTTP server at http://0.0.0.0:3100/ shutting down","time":"2022-08-11T06:51:47.179Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":30,"module":"Server","msg":"GraphQL HTTP server at http://0.0.0.0:3100/ shutting down","time":"2022-08-11T06:51:47.179Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":50,"err":{"errno":-3008,"code":"ENOTFOUND","syscall":"getaddrinfo","hostname":"postgres"},"msg":"getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND postgres","time":"2022-08-11T09:30:00.879Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":40,"module":"Db","msg":"pgSubscriber: Reconnecting attempt 1","time":"2022-08-11T09:30:00.882Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":40,"module":"Db","msg":"pgSubscriber: Reconnecting attempt 2","time":"2022-08-11T09:30:01.385Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":40,"module":"Db","msg":"pgSubscriber: Reconnecting attempt 3","time":"2022-08-11T09:30:01.888Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":40,"module":"Db","msg":"pgSubscriber: Reconnecting attempt 4","time":"2022-08-11T09:30:02.390Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":40,"module":"Db","msg":"pgSubscriber: Reconnecting attempt 5","time":"2022-08-11T09:30:02.892Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":40,"module":"Db","msg":"pgSubscriber: Reconnecting attempt 6","time":"2022-08-11T09:30:03.411Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":50,"module":"Db","err":{},"msg":"pgSubscriber","time":"2022-08-11T09:30:03.913Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":50,"err":{"errno":-3008,"code":"ENOTFOUND","syscall":"getaddrinfo","hostname":"postgres"},"msg":"getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND postgres","time":"2022-08-11T09:30:05.035Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":40,"module":"Db","msg":"pgSubscriber: Reconnecting attempt 1","time":"2022-08-11T09:30:05.037Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":40,"module":"Db","msg":"pgSubscriber: Reconnecting attempt 2","time":"2022-08-11T09:30:05.540Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":40,"module":"Db","msg":"pgSubscriber: Reconnecting attempt 3","time":"2022-08-11T09:30:06.042Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":40,"module":"Db","msg":"pgSubscriber: Reconnecting attempt 4","time":"2022-08-11T09:30:06.544Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":40,"module":"Db","msg":"pgSubscriber: Reconnecting attempt 5","time":"2022-08-11T09:30:07.051Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":40,"module":"Db","msg":"pgSubscriber: Reconnecting attempt 6","time":"2022-08-11T09:30:07.553Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":50,"module":"Db","err":{},"msg":"pgSubscriber","time":"2022-08-11T09:30:08.056Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":50,"err":{"errno":-3008,"code":"ENOTFOUND","syscall":"getaddrinfo","hostname":"postgres"},"msg":"getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND postgres","time":"2022-08-11T09:30:09.238Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":40,"module":"Db","msg":"pgSubscriber: Reconnecting attempt 1","time":"2022-08-11T09:30:09.240Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":40,"module":"Db","msg":"pgSubscriber: Reconnecting attempt 2","time":"2022-08-11T09:30:09.747Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":40,"module":"Db","msg":"pgSubscriber: Reconnecting attempt 3","time":"2022-08-11T09:30:10.249Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":40,"module":"Db","msg":"pgSubscriber: Reconnecting attempt 4","time":"2022-08-11T09:30:10.751Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":40,"module":"Db","msg":"pgSubscriber: Reconnecting attempt 5","time":"2022-08-11T09:30:11.253Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":40,"module":"Db","msg":"pgSubscriber: Reconnecting attempt 6","time":"2022-08-11T09:30:11.757Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":50,"module":"Db","err":{},"msg":"pgSubscriber","time":"2022-08-11T09:30:12.259Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":50,"err":{"errno":-3008,"code":"ENOTFOUND","syscall":"getaddrinfo","hostname":"postgres"},"msg":"getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND postgres","time":"2022-08-11T09:30:13.589Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":40,"module":"Db","msg":"pgSubscriber: Reconnecting attempt 1","time":"2022-08-11T09:30:13.592Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":40,"module":"Db","msg":"pgSubscriber: Reconnecting attempt 2","time":"2022-08-11T09:30:14.093Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":40,"module":"Db","msg":"pgSubscriber: Reconnecting attempt 3","time":"2022-08-11T09:30:14.596Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":30,"module":"Server","msg":"Initializing","time":"2022-08-11T09:30:14.625Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":30,"module":"HasuraClient","msg":"Initializing","time":"2022-08-11T09:30:14.875Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":30,"module":"HasuraClient","msg":"Initialized","time":"2022-08-11T09:42:50.345Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":30,"module":"CardanoNodeClient","msg":"Initializing. This can take a few minutes...","time":"2022-08-11T09:42:50.346Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":30,"module":"CardanoNodeClient","msg":"Initialized","time":"2022-08-11T10:31:58.840Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":30,"module":"MetadataFetchClient","msg":"Initializing","time":"2022-08-11T10:31:58.841Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":30,"module":"MetadataFetchClient","msg":"Initialized","time":"2022-08-11T10:31:59.037Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":30,"module":"ChainFollower","msg":"Initializing","time":"2022-08-11T10:31:59.037Z","v":0}
{"name":"cardano-graphql","hostname":"2f8ed0c5755a","pid":1,"level":30,"module":"ChainFollower","msg":"Initialized","time":"2022-08-11T10:31:59.041Z","v":0}
```

It doesn't display anything else after ChainFollower Initialized. Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waiting till db-sync gets to the latest epoch, I re-started docker container and it works fine.